# Store Multidimensional Array in Mysql PHP Code

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys just want to ask how can i store multidimensional array in mysql?
My table format is like this:

Sales Table

```
| sales id |  fkmember | date_of_sales
```

Sales Line Table

```
|  line id | fkproduct | fksales | qty_purchased
```

My array is this:

```
foreach($products as $element => $inner_array){
    echo "<strong>Product ID: ".$element."</strong><br>";
    foreach($inner_array as $items){
        echo $items."<br>";
    }
}
```

How can i put the data in my tables?

Comment: show us structure of the array.

Comment: It's highly possible that you should be going about this a different way entirely. I.e. storing each array item in a separate row. I agree, show us an example array.

Answer (score 1):

You can try serialization of array, very similar to what Wordpress does, to store configuration values

Comment: My array looks like this:                                                                                                                                                         [4]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["product_name"]=>
    string(17) "SAMSUNG GALXAY S3"
    ["product_desc"]=>
    string(9) "Cellphone"
    ["product_price"]=>
    string(7) "5000.00"
    ["product_qty"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["product_amount"]=>
    float(5000)
    ["product_code"]=>
    string(14) "SAMS2012-38714"
  }

Comment: If the products shown are product from sale, i would suggest you to have this stored individually in a table, say table name `sales_item`, and not serialized array.

By storing it in table it helps, to run various queries you might need in future to mine the data for statistics. For e.g. products most sold, etc.

Answer (score -4):

Use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function which turns the array of column values into a string.

```
foreach($inner_array as $items) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Sales (salesid, fkmember, date_of_sales, lineid, fkproduct, fksales, qty_purchased ) VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $items) . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: what if there is a single-quote ( ' ) on one of the item? [have a look here](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: You are using query in a loop ?? it decreases the speed of execution

Comment: By the way im using the codeigniter framework how can i do with it?

Comment: i created a function named r_implode() and it rerieves the array into string with a separator of comma(,) now i want to pass it to mysql how can i do this?